# Fscanf and omit fields like in C

Tags: go

Is it possible to omit fields like in C where you can `%*s`?

```
var pid int
fmt.Fscanf(r, "%*s %d", &pid)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can't do that in Go (at least on Go 1.21.0).

The [source code](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.0:src/fmt/scan.go) shows that:

- there is no verb to omit a field in a format string (like `%*s` in C): actually, the verb for strings is always a [**single** character](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.0:src/fmt/scan.go;l=824-825) (`%s`, `%v`, `%q`, `%x` or `%X`)
- the [`Fscanf`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.0:src/fmt/scan.go;l=141) method [iterates on **arguments**](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.0:src/fmt/scan.go;l=1228-1230) (`a` array in `Fscanf(r io.Reader, format string, a ...any)`). As a result, you **have to** define an argument in `a`, even if you don't care about its value

If you don't want to define a variable though, you can use:

```golang
var pid int
fmt.Fscanf(r, "%s %d", new(string), &pid)
```

#### Other alternatives

For your specific case though, to parse something from a reader, you can first read the reader into a string (e.g. `io.ReadAll`):

```golang
// read the reader into a string
s, err := io.ReadAll(r)
if err != nil {
    panic(err) // handle the error
}
```

And then either use `strings.Split` method, or a regex, like:

1. with `strings.Split`

```golang
pidString := strings.Split(string(s), " ")[1]
pid, err := strconv.Atoi(pidString)
if err != nil {
    panic(err) // handle the error
}
```

2. with a regex:

```golang
re := regexp.MustCompile(`[^\s]+ (?P<pid>\d+)`) // similar to "%s %d"
matches := re.FindStringSubmatch(s)
pidString := matches[re.SubexpIndex("pid")]
pid, err := strconv.Atoi(pidString)
if err != nil {
    panic(err) // handle the error
}
```

There are probably other methods but these ones should be enough for illustration. Hope that helps.